# Silverlight - Taking a "screenshot" from within silverlight itself?

Tags: image, silverlight-3.0

This is kind of vague as the control has not been designed yet and I thought I would ask before going with it.

I will have a control that shows an object within Silverlight.

The user can rotate the object etc.

Now, the user needs to be able to copy what they see to an image. Is this possible somehow, or do I have to render it somewhere else?

So it's not a screenshot per se, but a printable image of a specific control / area of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://blog.blueboxes.co.uk/2009/07/21/rendering-xaml-to-a-jpeg-using-silverlight-3/

In Silverlight 3 there is way to write XAML to WriteableBitmap. Technique is shown in above blog.

Comment: I did the same but additionally I upload the screen to my server, to provide best customer support ever ;-)  http://blog.gfader.com/2010/06/customer-support-in-silverlight.html